# What is needed in a php log in form

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I'm having problems with my log in php file. I completed my sign up form, which takes data and saves it in a database. I now want to be able to log in with the data from the db. This is my first log in form and I'm not sure if I have all the things needed to make it run or if there's just an error. A list of what is needed to make this log in form will help, Thank you. I would also like to mention that I have more data in the DB other than email/password.

```
<?php
$db  = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "test");


  if(!$db){die('could not connect:'.mysql_error());}

    echo'connected successfully';


 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $username = $_POST['Email'];
 $password = $_POST['Password'];

  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($Email);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($Password);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE Email ='$Email' AND 
   Password='$Password'";
 mysql_select_db('test');
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($count == 1) {
 echo "<script> alert('You Have Successfully Logged In')</script>";

exit();
} else {
 echo "<script> alert('Invalid Username and/or Password')</script>";
 }
 }

  mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Drop this tutorial that you're following, and find a newer one. The one you are using is super old, and will not work with newer versions of PHP. It's also highly insecure. Google for "php login password_hash prepared statement"

Comment: Consider learning a framework like Laravel instead, which handles all this for you.

Comment: @Qirel I would argue that learning solid skills in "basic" PHP first is a better approach. Lots of newer people seem lost because they can't make much of anything work without a framework, as everything they learned was around one. Also gives you a better understanding of how things work.

Comment: as Qirel said, this tutorial is so old, the mysql extension is deprecated now, use mysqli instead, also your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, which will teach you bad practices to deal with SQL queries.

Comment: Well MySqli (with an `i`) was added in PHP5.0 If I remember right, that was around 2005ish.... So that is what 14 years or so sense this should have been conveted to at least that. Certainly sense 5.3 (around 2009 when I started coding PHP, well I started in 2008)  I briefly used MySql (no `i`), that was mainly due to legacy code (that I eventually replaced ... ).  Anyway good luck, find a modern tutorial.

Comment: @Jeto Sure, I agree - basics in PHP is a necessity when you're working in any PHP environment. But that doesn't mean that learning frameworks is a bad thing ;-)

Comment: Frameworks are the architecture or scaffold used to build your application, if you have a tiny application, you should use a tiny framework .... lol.  You don't need a 20 story crane to build a 1 story home... That is how I feel about it.

Comment: I will check out the framework mentioned above, and yes, I will drop the tutorial I was reading, I didn't know it was outdated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You parse the POSTed EMAIL to your $username variable, but in your SELECT statement, you use a $Email variable. Perhaps this should have been your $Username variable instead, as this seems to hold your emailadress.

So your problem is in mixing of email and username. Correct this and your script should work.